# Algorithm for determing a ranking after choosing repeatedly between to items

Tags: algorithm, statistics, ranking, recommendation-engine

I would like to write a little program to help me rank items based on the result of a lot of one on one comparisons.

So if I have 100 items i would let users repeatedly choose between two randomly selected items of this set. Let's say there were 10.000 votes in total. Item Nr. 10 came up in 1000 votes and won all direct confrontations against all other items. Item Nr. 90 came up in 100 votes and won 40 and lost 60 direct confrontations.
Is there an existing algorithm (e.g. from recommender systems or similar) that I can utilize to construct a ranked list of these items?

Comment: Array sorting ?  That is not very subtle but it could do the job, given the way you want to compare items. Otherwise, you can try to construct a [tournament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tournament_(graph_theory)) from your comparisons, and see if the obtained tournament is transitive or not. If it is transitive you've won, you have a totla order on your items.

Comment: Not exactly what you are describing, but you might want to check out revealed preference theory and the Afriat's theorem from economics.

Comment: Otherwise, if you feel like tackling some nice NP-hard problem, you can solve your problem optimally using [feedback vertex set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_vertex_set). But I guess that's a tad overkill in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to rank based on the `win percentage` that is `total wins/total confrontations`

Incase you want to have a singular scoring mechanism, you can `reward` the winner and `punish` the loser by a fixed amount, and then rank based on the final score.

Finally, you can have a look at the [`Elo ranking algorithm`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/elo-rating-algorithm/), it calculated the probability of each item winning the confrontation and `rewards and punishes` relative to these probabilities.

Example

```
# Probability
A higher chance of winning than B

# Case1: A wins
A +small reward
B -small punishment

# Case2: B wins
A -large punishment
B +large reward
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I will look into the Eli ranking algorithm. Seems like this is what I was looking for and it totally makes sense in this context.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do what you explained (you didn't ask for any optimization or similar), then the algorithm is very simple.

1. Build a matrix of all possible comparisons.
2. Rank each element by the amount of wins in its column.

In pseudo code this could look like this:

```
# given a list of elements:
elements = ...

# build the comparison matrix:
matrix = Matrix(n, n)
for i in 0..n-1:
  for j in 0..n-1:
    matrix[i][j] = elements[i] < elements[n]

# rank each element by its "wins":
for i in 0..n-1:
  ranks[i] = sum(matrix[i])
```

After this `ranks[i]` will state the rank of `elements[i]` for each *i*, so you could sort your `elements` by the `ranks`.

Comment: You are right, that I didn't ask for optimization and your answer works for limited datasets. But when the number of elements grows, that mechanism isn't feasible anymore. Also the items that are randomly chosen more often, are ranked higher.